# electron app json data to renderer using ipc

Tags: javascript, html, electron, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

i am new to electron so im sorry if my question is childish
but i have sent some user inout data as object from renderer to main to store in json file (electron-db)
but i want to show all data in a table
i tired this by event.reply but it giving my desired result in preload's log only
i dont know how to take it from preload to html table
here i have attached my code from main

```js
// catch obj This is Main.js
ipcMain.on("message", (event, obj) => {
  db.createTable("medicine", (succ, msg) => {
    // succ - boolean, tells if the call is successful
    if (succ) {
      console.log(msg);
    } else {
      console.log("An error has occured. " + msg);
    }
  });

  console.warn(obj);
  if ((db.valid("medicine"), location)) {
    db.insertTableContent("medicine", obj, (succ, msg) => {
      // succ - boolean, tells if the call is successful
      console.log("Success: " + succ);
      console.log("Message: " + msg);
    });
  }
  let row;
  const app = electron.app || electron.remote.app;

  db.getAll("medicine", (succ, data) => {
    // succ - boolean, tells if the call is successful
    // data - array of objects that represents the rows.
    // console.warn(data);
    row = data;
  });
  console.warn(row)
  event.reply("message", row)
});
```

and this is my preload

```js
const {contextBridge, ipcMain, ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

const API = {
    sendmsg: (obj) => ipcRenderer.send("message", obj)
}
// const getAllData = function fetchData(){
//       ipcRenderer.send("req", "this is requirment for All data")
// }
ipcRenderer.on("message", (_event, row) => {
    console.log(row)
  })
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", API);
```

`consol.log(row)` giving my an array of all data in my db
but i dont know how to make it availabe in html files script or in renderer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiring of your IPC is a bit mixed up and confusing. To simplify your scripts, try separating them into their own functionality. IE: Use your `preload.js` script to allow communication between the main process and render process(es) only.

Not knowing what database you are using, I will assume your database code is correct and functional.

Below is an example of how I would set-up my `preload.js` script and use it to communicate between processes.

---

This `preload.js` script uses whitelisted channel names to identify which IPC lines of communication can be used, similar to [Node.js eventName](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/events.html).

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': [
            'message' // Channel name
        ]
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

For brevity, I have included your database code within the below `main.js` file.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
'use strict';

const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

// db = require('db'); // Your (connected) database

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

// From render to main and back again
electronIpcMain.handle('message', (event, obj) => {
    // Create the table
    db.createTable("medicine", (succ, msg) => {
        if (succ) {
            console.log(msg);
        } else {
            console.log('An error has occurred. ' + msg);
        }
    });

    console.warn(obj);

    // Insert your data object
    if ((db.valid("medicine"), location)) {
        db.insertTableContent("medicine", obj, (succ, msg) => {
            console.log('Success: ' + succ);
            console.log('Message: ' + msg);
        });
    }

    let rows;

    // Retrieve all rows
    db.getAll("medicine", (succ, data) => {
        // succ - boolean, tells if the call is successful
        // data - array of objects that represents the rows.
        // console.warn(data);
        rows = data;
    });

    console.warn(rows);

    return rows; // Simple return the result via IPC

    // Testing purposes.
    // let rows = [
    //     {"name": "Amoxicillin", "weight": "250mg"},
    //     {"name": "Codeine", "weight": "50mg"},
    //     {"name": "Penicillin", "weight": "25mg"}
    // ];
    //
    // rows.push(obj);
    //
    // console.log(rows);
    //
    // return rows;
})
```

---

Lastly, I have tried to implement what the basic functionality of your `index.html` file may be like.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Medicine</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Add Medicine</h1>
    
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input id="name" type="text">

        <label for="weight">Weight: </label>
        <input id="weight" type="text">

        <input id="button" type="button" value="Add">
    </body>

    <script>
        let name = document.getElementById('name');
        let weight = document.getElementById('weight');

        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            // From render to main and (.then) back again
            window.ipcRender.invoke('message', {"name": name.value, "weight": weight.value})
                .then((rows) => {
                    console.log(rows);
                })
        })
    </script>
</html>
```